# Linq left outer join with multiple condition

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

I am new to `Linq`. I am trying to query some data in `MS SQL`.

Here is my statement:

```
select * from booking
left outer join carpark
    on booking.bookingId = carpark.bookingId
where userID = 5 and status = 'CL'
```

When I run this in `MS SQL`, I get the expected result. How can I do this in `Linq`?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Doing left outer joins with LINQ is a commonly-asked question on StackOverflow.  Try [searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=linq%20left%20join%20site:stackoverflow.com) and you should find numerous examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need this:

```
var query = (from t1 in tb1
             join t2 in tb2 on t1.pKey = t2.tb1pKey into JoinedList
             from t2 in JoinedList.DefaultIfEmpty()
             where t1.userID == 5 && t1.status == "CL"
             select new 
             {
                  t1,
                  t2
             })
             .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do left join this way :

```
from t1 in tb1
from t2 in tb2.Where(o => o.tb1pKey == t1.pKey).DefaultIfEmpty()
where tb1.userId == 5 && tb1.status == "CL"
select t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually when people say they want a "left outer join," that's just because they've already converted what they *really* want into SQL in their head. Usually what they really want is all of the items from table A, and the ability to get the related items from table B if there are any.

Assuming you have your navigation properties set up correctly, this could be as easy as:

```
var tb1sWithTb2s = context.tb1
    .Include(t => t.tb2s)       // Include all the tb2 items for each of these.
    .Where(t => t.userID == 5 and t.status = "CL");
```